# Where is it better to update the values of the hooks if the value received from the server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have useEffect, which gets two values from server 1, price of item 2, name of item. when I use the setPriceSquanchy functions (obj.price) setNameSquanchy (obj.name). my code is updated twice there is no way to make it so that it is updated only once.

```
import React, { useState,useEffect} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [priceSquanchy, setPriceSquanchy] = useState("");
  const [nameSquanchy, setNameSquanchy] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://foo0022.firebaseio.com/vz.json`
    );
    const obj = await res.json();
     setPriceSquanchy(obj.price)
     setNameSquanchy(obj.name)
  })();

}, []);
console.log("Hello")
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: nameSquanchy is not a function. You meant setNameSquanchy, didn't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR [Your sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/8xzxmvx5o2). [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/32m793q50p) is the fixed version (another fix with `ReactDOM.unstable_batchUpdates` [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/04lv4w068w))**

So your component is rendered twice after the promise is resolved right? Like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/zw8l8p22mm) logs "App invoked" twice after logging "setting states". This is because first `setA` is called, then `setB` is called both causing a render.

In my opinion this is fine because anyway React will only apply the necessary patches to the DOM. It won't be a huge performance difference even if you fix it.

But if you want to fix it you can have a state containing both price and name something like `{ price: "", name: "" }` in that way you'll only call `setPriceName({ price: newPrice, name: newName })`. [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mr9w1klyp). As you see in this demo "App invoked" is only logged once after "setting states" is logged.

If you don't want to do that you can also use `ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates` like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/ryzmklj7xp). As you can see this also works but it's "unstable". More on the API by Dan [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10231#issuecomment-316644950) and in [this thread](https://mobile.twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1103358427278069760) too

Also, at times React could also batch updates from `setA` and `setB` thus causing only one render. Like [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ywn3mx1xy1). Here it got batched together because it didn't had a timeout and it was immediately after first render.

**Focusing more on the question "Where is it better to update the values of the hooks if the value received from the server?"...**

What you are doing is pretty correct. Another way would be making a container component for fetching the data then having a presentational component to actually render it. I don't really like this approach (nor does Dan suggests it now xD) it's really an overkill. You can read more on that [here](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).

PS: Also in case you are wondering why there are still two renders in your sample's fixed version, well the first one is the initial render. So there's basically only one update after the promise is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` is used for side effects.

From React Docs

> Accepts a function that contains imperative, possibly effectful code.
>   Mutations, subscriptions, timers, logging, and other side effects are not allowed inside the main body of a function component (referred to as React’s render phase). Doing so will lead to confusing bugs and inconsistencies in the UI.
>   Instead, use useEffect. The function passed to useEffect will run after the render is committed to the screen.

Now, what you're doing is in fact a side effect ( AJAX call) and here's a working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/p1j950pjq) to achieve the same via `useEffect`.

Notice the use of second argument to `useEffect`. This is dependency array and `useEffect` will only fire accordingly. By supplying an empty array, I make sure it fires runs only once. Failing to do this will continuously call this function in our component. You can also control it's firing based on some other state variables. More on reading [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect).

Comment: I did not understand what ajax side effect is that it changes the value of priceSquanchy nameSquanchy asynchronously?

Comment: Ajax side effect means that you are getting out ot React world and making contact with Browser API (fetch in this case) and the update that happens therefore is a side effect. Shall I demo the exact code or will you be able to make modifications based on the example ?

Comment: Sorry for the long answer. Show your example so that I understand better what you were saying. I will try to explain with an example what I need. I need to get the value from the server and then drop the priceSquanchy, nameSquanchy, shippingScanchy value. less. as I understand it is impossible to do with the help of fetch. As can be seen from my 1 example. How many times do you use the state function in then then so many times and the code is updated.

Comment: Now my question is, is there a way to make it so that the update is one time. I can show such an example in which the update is smaller but the code is worse. I do not like this decision. Maybe you know the best way.[1 cod](https://codesandbox.io/s/oo6n2zm1nz),[2 cod](https://codesandbox.io/s/ywlnyyk3w1)

Comment: Show your example? I already posted the working example in my answer as codesandbox link. It's a live example for fetching the data from server and updating it inside the hook(useEffect). This is your exact question I believe in the post.

Comment: What you can do is replace it with your API and update the setPriceSquanchy or whatever else you need in setState call.

Answer (score 0):

`useEffects` is a good place to do this. `useEffects` hook is intended for side effects, e.g. `fetch` request.

If a request is supposed to be done once on component mount and not on every render, `useEffects` should be used with empty inputs.

The function mixes `async..await` and promises in unnecessarily complex way.

It should be:

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const res = await fetch(
      `......`
    );
    const obj = await res.json();
    setPriceSquanchy(obj.price)
    setNameSquanchy(obj.name)
  })();

  // return fetch cancellation function
}, []);
```

Comment: Sorry for the long answer.When you use the asynchronous function, eslint swears. I don’t remember what it is connected with and it seems to be a bad idea.

Comment: It doesn't hurt anything but this may upset type checkers because destroy function is supposed to be returned from useEffect, not a promise. AIIFE that you originally used is a safer way to do this. Any way, you need either `then` or `async` there, not both.